# How do i loop through an array within an array in a database?

Tags: php

I have two image arrays in my mysql database that i am trying to loop through and display them. One array holds an array called 'postImage' of full size images, the other called 'thumbnail' holds thumbnails of those same images. However one array is for an `<a>` link that i want to direct to the full size image(s) and the other array is for an `<img>` tag inside the `<a>` link. What i'm trying figure out is how i can loop through both arrays but have each `<a>` link go to the correct matching full size image.

here is my code:

```
<?php foreach(json_decode($post->thumbnail) as $thumbnail) { ?>
  <?php foreach(json_decode($post->postImage) as $postImage) { ?>
    <a href="/storage/photos/{{$postImage}}">
      <img src="/storage/photos/{{$thumbnail}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Which columns does your array contain? Which colum should the links be joined on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use nested loops, that will produce a cross-product of all thumbnails and images.

Loop over one array, and use its index to access the corresponding element of the other array.

```
$thumbnails = json_decode($post->thumbnail);
$postImages = json_decode($post->postImage);
foreach ($thumbnails as $i => $thumbnail) {
    $postImage = $postImages[$i]; { ?>
    <a href="/storage/photos/{{$postImage}}">
      <img src="/storage/photos/{{$thumbnail}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```